# Как в Visual Studio C++/CLI  из одной формы обратиться к элементам другой?

Tags: winforms, .net, c++

Пусть есть две формы главная **Form1.h** и **Form2.h**

Как из формы **Form2.h** обратиться к элементам **Form1.h**

Читая различные форумы понял следующее: необходимо в параметрах конструктора второй формы объявить указатель на первую форму:

```
  Form2(Form1^ copyForm1)
  {
      // код конструктора   
  } ;
```

А в первой форме подать **this** в качестве параметра конструктора

```
  Form ^ Form2rel = gcnew Form2(this);
```

Тогда к элементам первой формы можно будет обращаться просто через указатель, например

```
  copyForm1->Label1->Text
```

Суть подхода понятна, но только указатель вида **Form1^ copyForm1** не объявляется, так как вторая форма не видит класс **Form1**, студия пишет **"неверный идентификатор Form1"**, а почему не понятно...

Пространство имен у них одно **Project1**, если приписать **Project1::Form1^ copyForm1**, то пишет **"Form1 не является членом Project1"**

Делать **#include "Form1.h"** в **Form2.h** не помогает - вылазят ошибки.

Объясните пожалуйста в чем проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На мой взгляд, у Вас неверный подход к проблеме, которая заключается в том, что нужно поменять содержимое элементов формы `Form1` в форме `Form2`. Эту проблему можно решить несколькими способами:

1. Объявить делегат и с помощью сообщения через этот делегат уведомить `Form1`, о том, чтобы она изменила свои поля.
2. Объявить интерфейс вида

   ```
   interface IEvent
   {
     virtual void SendText(String^ text) = 0;
    };
   ```

Отнаследовать `Form1` от `IEvent`, реализовать метод `SendText` и передать в конструктор указатель на `IEvent`:

```
#include "ivent.h" // файл в котором объявлен IEvent
Form2(IEvent^ pEvent);
```

Когда нужно в `Form2` изменить содержимое поля, тогда просто пишите `pEvent->SendText("qwerty");`.

Второй способ очень похож на то, что вы хотели, только нет жесткой зависимости от `Form1` в `Form2`.